# How do I execute commands in PHP / cPanel?

Tags: php

I am trying to add a "Login with Google" button on my webapp. Anyhow, going through the [instructions given here](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php), I notice that they are asking to execute a lot of commands such as

```
php -S localhost:4567
```

How and where do I copy these commands to get executed?

Comment: Log in via SSH and run them there.

Comment: theses are neither php or cPanel 'commands'